# Specify availability zone in Azure VM deployement using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have been trying to deploy a VM on specific availability zone on Azure using terraform .. i can specify the zone on the portal
[image: portal VM selection], according to the terraform registry documentation it has the zone option on the website : [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine#zone)

here is the code i tried :

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "linux-infra-test-group" {
  name = "linux-infra-test-group"
  size = "Standard_A2_v2"
  zone = ["2"]
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.location
  admin_username = "adminuser"
  admin_ssh_key {
    username = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }
  network_interface_ids = [ 
    azurerm_network_interface.nic-infra-test-group.id,
   ]
   os_disk {
     storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
     caching = "ReadWrite"
   }
   source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy"
    sku       = "22_04-lts"
    version   = "latest"
   }
   boot_diagnostics {
     storage_account_uri = null
   }
  tags = {
    Owner = "Infrastructure Team"
    Environment = "Infrastructure TEST"
  }
}
```

Comment: try updating zone = "2" @MantraReborn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried Specify availability zone in Azure VM deployment using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

According to Terraform Azure Provider documentation, the correct attribute to set the availability zone for a virtual machine is `zone` (for a single zone) or `zones` (for multiple zones). It should be specified as a string, not a list if you are targeting a single zone.

**My configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-infra-test-group" {
  name     = "rgvk-infra-test-group"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet-infra-test-group" {
  name                = "vnet-infra-test-group"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-infra-test-group" {
  name                 = "subnet-infra-test-group"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet-infra-test-group.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic-infra-test-group" {
  name                = "nic-infra-test-group"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet-infra-test-group.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "linux-infra-test-group" {
  name                = "linux-infra-test-group"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.location
  size                = "Standard_A2_v2"
  zone                = "2"  # Specify the availability zone
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "YourPassword"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic-infra-test-group.id,
  ]


  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = azurerm_storage_account.diag_storage_account.primary_blob_endpoint
  }

  tags = {
    Owner       = "Infrastructure Team"
    Environment = "Infrastructure TEST"
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.diag_storage_account ]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "diag_storage_account" {
  name                     = "diagstorageaccountvk"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg-infra-test-group.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello @Vinay B, I already tried that previously .. and also tried it again now, it does not take into consideration the zone 2 as I specify it in the terraform file: 
'resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "linux-infra-test-group" {
  name = "linux-infra-test-group"
  size = "Standard_A2_v2"
  zone = "2"
  '
, see image [link](https://imgur.com/LVmyzmu)

Comment: May I know the region you're provisioning the resources @MantraReborn?

Comment: West Europe @Vinay B

Comment: Try changing the location to other regions @MantraReborn

Comment: Hello again, the problem is we have a policy preventing us from deploying resources on other regions, and also to be honest I doubt that because it works using the GUI, could it really be the problem here ?
@Naveen Sharma : it didn't solve the problem for me, but Okay if you want I can accept it nevertheless :)

Comment: I reworked with using the West Europe location  working fine as expected
![link](https://i.imgur.com/m1itLbn.png)
![link](https://i.imgur.com/QsOFTQs.png)

Comment: this might be due to the policy that blocking you from picking up zone type 2 same as it restrict you select other regions. may be the policy restricting only to pick one region and one zone type. @MantraReborn

Comment: this is actually very strange indeed, because the deployement works fine using the portal (GUI) i can pick from Zone 1, 2 or 3 .. however using terraform it does not work, it deploys the VM without specifying the zone exactly. if there is any policy in place it wouldn't work also using the portal, right ?

Comment: I will accept the answer nevertheless, clearly it worked for you with no issues on both regions .. but to this day, I still don't get why it not working for me :(